# Is there a way to choose a specific representation when serializing a `ForeignKey`?

Tags: python, json, django

I have a very simple model in Django 1.9 (not using any additional RESTful frameworks or anything because I'm trying to keep the basics). `User` is just the default Django-Auth User.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    text = models.TextField(null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    modified_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)
```

When serializing for a JSON response, I use the following view:

```
items = []
for post in Post.objects.values():
    post['author'] = User.objects.get(pk=post['author_id']).username
    items.append(post)
return JsonResponse({'posts': items}, safe=False)
```

Is there a way to skip the retrieval of `author_id` and reinserting as `author`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understood you correctly.

The proper way to do this would be:

```
for post in Post.objects.values('id', 'name', 'author__username'):
    ...
```

This will, without the additional queries your current code would incur, add give you `post['author__username']`.

Although, since you're writing a RESTy framework, you probably care about the naming of the keys. Honestly, I have no better solution than this:

```
for post in ...:
    post['author'] = post['author__username']
    del post['author__username']
```

Comment: You got exactly at what I was getting at. I knew I was incurring those calls unnecessarily and wanted to fix that. What is the name of the `__` accessor notation?

Comment: I wouldn't call it an accessor, more a naming convention. It's django specific, and has no formal name as far as I know. But it's very similar to the `.` operator in most languages, which is used as an accessor, like you said. `author__username` is equivalent to `author.username` in "pure" Python.